# TopLevel window disappears when using askopenfilename, from tkinter.filedialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For my program I want the user to select a `file`, and I am using the `tkinter.filedialog` library to do this. However, when the `askopenfilename` dialog is opened, the `TopLevel`window disappears behind the main `Tk()` window.

> How would I stop this from happening?

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class MainWin(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.update()
        pu = PopUp(self)
        self.configure(width=500, height=300)


class PopUp(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(PopUp, self).__init__(master)

        def entry_set(entry, text):
            entry.delete(0, 'end')
            entry.insert(END, text)

        item_file = StringVar()
        item_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=item_file)
        item_entry.place(x=80, y=60, height=20, width=300)
        item_label = Label(self, text="item file: ", bg="gray74", relief="groove")
        item_label.place(x=20, y=60, height=20, width=60)
        item_button = Button(self, text="\uD83D\uDCC2", relief="groove",
                             command=lambda: entry_set(item_entry, askopenfilename()))
        item_button.place(x=380, y=60, height=20, width=20)
        self.configure(width=460, height=180)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MainWin()
    win.mainloop()
```

> ### Edit:
>
> I have realised that using the `.grab_set()` method works, and will make the 
>   `TopLevel()` window appear back on top of the `Tk()` after the file is chosen.

However, this still means the window disappears behind the `Tk()` window whilst picking a file, I would still love to find a solution to this, even though this is now just a visual problem, not a functional one.

Comment: On my windows the `Toplevel` didn't disappear. Are you sure its not just behind the main `Tk` window?

Comment: Yes I realized after I posted that was the case, however the question still remains, is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I don't notice such behave after I select a file the window remains on top of the `Tk()` or  you want the `Toplevel` window to be in focus after you select the file?

Comment: @Saad When I select a file the `Tk()` window remains on top of the `TopLevel()` window for me.

Comment: Try call `self.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)` and  `self.wm_attributes('-topmost', 0)` then `askopenfilename()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the `Toplevel` window a transient window, it will then be kept on top of its parent window:

```
class PopUp(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(PopUp, self).__init__(master)
        self.transient(master)
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without forcing the `Toplevel` on top?

Comment: @JanWillem I don't understand what you want.

Comment: The transient window will always stay on top of the parent window. What I want is a `Toplevel` that can be either on top or below the parent window, depending on what the user wants. However when the user opens the filedialog from the `Toplevel` I want the `Toplevel` to stay on top of the parent window. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Set the `Toplevel` be the parent of the file dialog.

Comment: Indeed. An `askopenfilename(parent=toplevelwindow)` does the job!